# get substring from the main string Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a `string` and I want to extract a `substring` from that main `string`

Some sample strings are:

```
http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx?tags=%7C105651%7C102496&Asidebar=1&dnr=y
http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx?tags=%7C12784%7C102496&index=28&showFromBeginning=true&
```

I want to get the `tags value`.

In this case:

```
val = %7C105651%7C102496

val = %7C12784%7C102496
```

Is there any chance to get that?

**Edit**

```
tags = re.search('tags=(.+?)&Asidebar', url)
print tags
if tags:
    found = tags.group(1)
    print (found)
output: None
```

Note: I've just tried to get something from the first string only

Comment: There is a great chance. Can you show us what you came up with so far?

Comment: sure, wait, I'm editing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`urlparse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and [`cgi.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs) (Python 2.x):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> import cgi
>>>
>>> s = 'http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx?tags=%7C105651%7C102496&Asidebar=1&dnr=y'
>>> cgi.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)
{'dnr': ['y'], 'Asidebar': ['1'], 'tags': ['|105651|102496']}
>>> cgi.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)['tags'][0]
'|105651|102496'
```

In Python 3.x, use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>>
>>> s = 'http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx?tags=%7C105651%7C102496&Asidebar=1&dnr=y'
>>> urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(s).query)['tags'][0]
'|105651|102496'
```

Comment: really thanks. but it seems it is pretty advance.. I'm new to PY and will stick to easyone

Thanks for your effort

Comment: @MMK, Isn't this easy? The function will care edge case for you. Try `http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx?tags=%7C105651%7C102496` / `http://domain.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx?tags=`

Comment: sure..I'm checking it.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. You don't need to write `Asidebar` in your regex. Because in your second input string, there isn't a substring called `Asidebar`.

```
tags = re.search('tags=(.+?)&', url)
if tags:
    found = tags.group(1)
    print (found)
```